# amsmath package clash

Tags: packages, amsmath, cleveref

Just this afternoon I seem to have a package clash that resulted in all my equation numbers disappearing. I seem to have resolved the issue by putting `\usepackage{amsmath}` at the top of the preamble rather than halfway down, where it has been for the last couple of years. In particular, it seems I need to load `amsmath` before `cleveref`. I am sure this is new today. I am now worried that there might be some other package clash caused by moving `amsmath` to the top (although it seems to be compiling OK now).

M(non-W)E

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:j}
  J = \frac{1}{2}(a - b)
\end{equation}

I want to reference \cref{eq:j}

\end{document}
```

Does this work for anyone else? I use MikTex2.9 by the way. Are there likely to be any other package clashes caused by moving `amsmath` to the top?

Including my full package list just in case anyone can spot something wrong:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}                % allow different line spacing
\usepackage[showframe, top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % allows < > to work properly
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}       % gives bold italic font
\usepackage{import}        % import files from subdirectories
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries} % add a glossary
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}      % reference object types automatically
\usepackage{url}                     % split URLs across lines
\usepackage{graphicx}      % needed for including graphics
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{placeins}      % insert floatbarriers
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=0,font={sf,small},labelfont=bf]{caption, subfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}               % allow formatting of appendix titles
\usepackage{subdepth}                   % allow more levels of subsection
\usepackage{sectsty}          % put section headings in sans-serif font
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}                   % allow placement of fractions in text
\usepackage{xspace}                  % automatically put spaces after defined symbols
\usepackage{siunitx}          % good unit formatting
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
```

Comment: `cleverref` is documented as having to be loaded 'late'

Comment: @JosephWright I can't understand it though, I didn't change anything about the order of those two. I'd been playing around with my bibligraphy and added `hyphenat` but even removing that made no difference. I know I didn't change the order because I pulled the old file out of dropbox ;-)

Comment: What about [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) - it loads [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). So, if you had `mathtools` loaded *before* [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) everything would have worked fine. Did you change any other package orders?

Comment: @Werner thanks for that also. I have just double checked: at some point I moved `tocloft` from below 'url' to above `cleveref` - but it is still there and it doesn't seem to be complaining about that. This package stuff is fraught with danger - that list has been compiled gradually over about five years - how anyone's supposed to remember what clashes with what I don't know!

Comment: You load the obsolete package `subfigure` and also, in a very non standard way, `subfig`; remove `subfigure` and move `subfig` to `\usepackage{subfig}` by itself.

Comment: @egreg I am not loading `subfigure`... at least not intentionally - I believed I had to add that option to `tocloft` to list them in the LOF... are you telling me that actually loads `subfigure` - maybe I misread the documentation? I suspect the `subfig` thing was copied from some very simple example file right at the beginning before I added all the `caption` options, but you're right that is a bit messy.

Answer (score 5):

`amsmath` isn't usually a problem when loaded near the top.  however, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so a better approach would be to simply load `mathtools` at the top, and omit loading `amsmath`.